# Can not convert a file to base64 encoding using node.js

Tags: node.js, base64, fs

I am trying to read file from directory and convert its content to base64 encoding but I am getting result as blank. I am explaining my code below.

```
const configAvtar = _.get(req, ['files', 'configFile']);
configAvtar.mv('./uploads/' + configAvtar.name);
const contents = fs.readFileSync(`${process.env['root_dir']}/uploads/${configAvtar.name}`, {encoding: 'base64'});
console.log('contents', contents);
```

Here first I am uploading file and then covert those file content to base64 encoding but in console I am getting the blank output. I need to convert the files content into base64 encoding and get the encoded output.

Comment: You could try these two approaches:


`const contents = 
fs.readFileSync(${process.env['root_dir']}/uploads/${configAvtar.name})`

`const contentToBase64 = contents.toString('base64')`


Or with a buffer: 



`return new Buffer(contents).toString('base64')`

Comment: I tried. same result coming. BTW its one .xml file.

Comment: I see, maybe you could try converting the XML to string first, and then you can try to encode it to Base64.

Comment: I have posted my all code. Here my objective is I have to covert any file content into base64 encoded format. For now its one xml file but it could be any type of file.

Comment: Can you post your answer ?

Comment: I tried this with a XML file:

`const fs = require('fs');

const content = fs.readFileSync('test.xml');

const toBase64 = Buffer.from(content).toString('base64');

console.log(toBase64);`

It works, and it'll probably work for any file.

Comment: same issue after modification also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222971/discussion-between-danibrum-and-subhra-edqart).